# The button Back in States, aiogram is not clickable

Tags: python, bots, telegram, aiogram

So, when I try to press on button 'Back' it just does nothing, absolutely, here's the code:

Aiogram, python

I've tried to add state in the button's function, and it still didn't work

```py
async def back_to_admin(state=None):
    print(state)

    if state is not None:
        await state.finish()

    reply = InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)

    reply.insert(InlineKeyboardButton('⬅️ Back', callback_data='admin'))

    return reply

async def add_proxy(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await call.message.edit_text(' Enter proxy:',
        reply_markup=await back_to_admin(state),
        parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)

    await state.update_data({
        'state': 'add_acc',
        'message_id': call.message.message_id,
    })

    await Admin.step1.set()
```